# PhP Search Directory By File Extension

Tags: php, file, directory

I have a script and a function in it gets every file in that folder. How can I edit this code to make it so it only gets .png files?

```
public function GetPreviews($category)
    {
        $directories = glob("assets/preview/$category/*");
        $directory = array();
        foreach($directories as $directories)
        {
            $directory[] = str_replace("assets/preview/$category/", "", $directories);   
        }
        return $directory;      
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

add .png to glob("assets/preview/$category/*.png");

```
public function GetPreviews($category)
    {
        $directories = glob("assets/preview/$category/*.png");
        $directory = array();
        foreach($directories as $directories)
        {
            $directory[] = str_replace("assets/preview/$category/", "", $directories);   
        }
        return $directory;      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `glob()` - just add `.png` after the last `*`

Like so:

```
public function GetPngs($category)
    {
        $directories = glob("assets/preview/$category/*.png");
        $directory = array();
        foreach($directories as $directories)
        {
            $directory[] = str_replace("assets/preview/$category/", "", $directories);   
        }
        return $directory;      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing '.png' in your code just change

```
$directories = glob("assets/preview/$category/*");
```

to

```
$directories = glob("assets/preview/$category/*.png");
```